# How to print a number pattern square in java

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program that outputs:

```
12345
54321
12345
54321
12345
```

So far I have done:

```
public class GotThatBoom {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int row, col, num;
        for (row = 1; row <= 5; row++) {
            num = row;
            for (col = 1; col <= 5; col++) {
                System.out.printf("%d ", num);
                num++;
                if ()
            }
            System.out.printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

But the output I am getting is:

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 8
5 6 7 8 9
```

Can you help me, Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. On topic and how to ask apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, debugging, or tutorial service. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: According to your question specifications, what's stopping you from doing: `System.out.println("12345");System.out.println("54321");`... See the problem when it comes to unclear questions? You've provided your attempt, but you haven't provided a valid question.

Comment: Please note: If the font the console is using is NOT a sansserif font, you are not going to get a box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your row number is even, you want to print from 5 to 1, and when it is odd, you'd want to print it 1 to 5.
So:

```
public class GotThatBoom {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int row, col;
        for (row = 1; row <= 5; row++) {
            for (col = 1; col <= 5; col++) {
                if( row %2 == 0) 
                System.out.printf("%d ", col);
                else
                System.out.printf("%d", 6 - col );
            }
            System.out.printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Sir, for helping me @tsamridh86

Comment: if you think the answer is correct, please mark it accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

when your row is odd you go from 1 to 5 and when its odd you are going 5 to 1:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int row = 1; row <= 5; row++) {
        for (int col = 1; col <= 5; col++) {
            if (row % 2 != 0) {
                System.out.printf("%d ", col);
            } else {
                System.out.printf("%d ", 6 - col);
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("\n");
    }
}
```

**output**:

```
1 2 3 4 5 
5 4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4 5 
5 4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4 5
```